# How to add custom extension for QuickLook?

Tags: macos, finder, plist, quicklook

Does anybody know of a method of previewing **.WebM** files in QuickLook? 
 I've searched on google but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding it via the .plist file.

[This guide will explain how to do it.](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/09/25/tuaw-tip-add-file-extensions-to-quick-look/)

To summarize the steps:

1. Go to the applications folder
2. Locate **TextEdit.app**
3. Show Package Contents
4. Edit the **Info.plist** file